# spring integration with multiple defaultmessagelistenercontainer (with transactionManager) and multiple <jms:outbound-channel-adapter> and

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a spring integration application with a requirement of  2 `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (with `transactionManager`) and 2 `jms:outbound-channel-adapter`.

I have configured each listener container with `"property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"` and also  `"property name="transactionManager" ref="platformTransactionManager"` .

But for the transaction manager i have used again a different `jmsConnectionFactory` . I am  not using a `CachingConnectionFactory` in the listener container but using it in `platformTransactionManager` . For `jms:outbound-channel-adapter` again i am using the same `jmsConnectionFactory` which i have used in listener container.

My problem is that with this configuration i am hitting the no. of connections exceeding the limit (150) to a MQ channel in a high load condition.

I tried many different ways but i don't see the no. of connection getting down once it gets up , using below configuration for `cachingFactory`

```
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new 
CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(true);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(16);`
```

i tried

1)sharing the `jmsConnectionFactory` between the `listenerContainer` and the `platformTransactionManager` but the txn doesn't work correctly as i see the messages getting sent in incorrect order

2)using the `cachingConenctionFactory in the`listenerContainer` , but still i see the same no. of connections

Should i use 3 different `jmsConnectionFactory`  for the listener, `txnmanager` and the sender?

What would be best configuration here, please suggest , many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think with IBM MQ you can't use `CachingConnectionFactory`, but instead this one as:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.DelegatingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="imbMqFactory"/>
    <property name="shouldStopConnections" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

This single `connectionFactory` must be used from the TX manager and from the containers.